# Drag and drop not enabled

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu 23.10.1 in VirtualBox hosted by Windows 11. I have installed `guest additions` and have set shared clipboard and drag and drop in bidirectional way. But both of these features not working. I get mouse pointer "not allowed" while trying to drag and drop form host to Ubuntu machine. How to fix that?

[image]

Comment: Can you try a different mouse ?  Did you restart both machines (host and guest) ?

Comment: I have restarted both machines, but this not helped. I have copied virtual machine into other computer with different mouse ant keyboard. This not helped either.